# setState inside Promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in my React code defined like this:

```
getAttachment(url) {
    fetch(url).then((responseText) => {

        var response = responseText.json();

        response.then(function(response){
            this.setState({ attachment: response });
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

But I get an error when this compiles, saying that I have an unexpected token at the `.bind(this)`. Any ideas, how to set state inside a promise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of binding `this` you could just scope the reference to `this`. like

```
var that = this;
```

and then reference `that.setState`.

Answer (score 8):

This has because you have a different scope inside the function. When using a function it has it's own scope. And "this" used out side the function is not the same when you use it inside the function. The best way of doing this is having a variable "that" and assign the previous "this" to "that".

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getAttachment = this.getAttachment.bind(this);
        this.state = {attachmenet: ""};
    }

    getAttachment(url) {

         //Code you need to add
         var that = this;

         fetch(url).then((responseText) => {

            var response = responseText.json();

            response.then(function(response){
               //code you need to change
               that.setState({ attachment: response });
            });
         });
     }

     render() {
         this.getAttachment();
         return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.state.attachment}}>
       </div>;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the `getAttachment` function to 
`getAttachment = (url) => {...}` and delete `.bind(this)`